# How to get lastpage of totalresult in yahoo boss

Tags: json, yahoo-boss-api

I have a json like this from my query:

> {"bossresponse":{"responsecode":"200","web":{"start":"0","count":"10","totalresults":"1050000000","results":[{"date": "","clickurl":"http://www.yahoo.com/","url":"http://www.yahoo.com/","dispurl":"www.yahoo</b>.com","title":"Yahoo</b>!","abstract":"Welcome to Yahoo</b>!, the world's most visited home page. Quickly find what you're searching for, get in touch with friends and stay in-the-know with the latest news and ..."},{"date": "","clickurl":"http://news.yahoo.com/world/","url":"http://news.yahoo.com/world/","dispurl":"news.yahoo</b>.com/world","title":"World News Headlines - Yahoo</b>! News","abstract":"Get the latest world news headlines from Yahoo</b>! News. Find breaking world news, including analysis and opinion on top world stories."},{"date": "","clickurl":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo","url":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo","dispurl":"en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo</b>","title":"Yahoo</b>! - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia","abstract":"Yahoo</b>! Inc. (NASDAQ: YHOO) is an American multinational internet corporation headquartered in Sunnyvale, California, United States. The company is perhaps best known ..."},{"date": "","clickurl":"http://mail.yahoo.com/","url":"http://mail.yahoo.com/","dispurl":"mail.yahoo</b>.com","title":"Yahoo</b>! Mail: The best web-based email!","abstract":"Your World. Your Way. Yahoo</b>! makes it easy to enjoy what matters most in your world. Best in class Yahoo</b>! Mail, breaking local, national and global news, finance ..."},{"date": "","clickurl":"http://my.yahoo.com/","url":"http://my.yahoo.com/","dispurl":"my.yahoo</b>.com","title":"Sign in to Yahoo</b>!","abstract":"My Yahoo</b> is a customizable web page with news, stock quotes, weather, and many other features."},{"date": "","clickurl":"http://au.yahoo.com/?p=us","url":"http://au.yahoo.com/?p=us","dispurl":"au.yahoo</b>.com/?p=us","title":"Yahoo</b>!7","abstract":"The Yahoo</b>! for Australia offering local & global search, free email, instant messaging, news, sport, travel, shopping, movies & music."},{"date": "","clickurl":"http://omg.yahoo.com/","url":"http://omg.yahoo.com/","dispurl":"omg.yahoo</b>.com","title":"omg! Celebrity gossip, news photos, babies, couples, hotties ...","abstract":"The latest celebrity gossip from Yahoo</b>! OMG! Get the latest news and gossip on the Hollywood celebrities with videos and photos."},{"date": "","clickurl":"http://finance.yahoo.com/?u","url":"http://finance.yahoo.com/?u","dispurl":"finance.yahoo</b>.com/?u","title":"Yahoo</b>! Finance - Business Finance, Stock Market, Quotes, News","abstract":"At Yahoo</b>! Finance, you get free stock quotes, up to date news, portfolio management resources, international market data, message boards, and mortgage rates that help ..."},{"date": "","clickurl":"http://news.yahoo.com/","url":"http://news.yahoo.com/","dispurl":"news.yahoo</b>.com","title":"Yahoo</b>! News - Latest News & Headlines","abstract":"The latest news and headlines from Yahoo</b>! News. Get breaking news stories and in-depth coverage with videos and photos."},{"date": "","clickurl":"http://search.yahoo.com/","url":"http://search.yahoo.com/","dispurl":"search.yahoo</b>.com","title":"Yahoo</b>! Search - Web Search","abstract":"The search engine that helps you find exactly what you're looking for. Find the most relevant information, video, images, and answers from all across the Web."}]}}}

In that json you can see 'totalresults' is '1050000000' this is not total result for list, but total documents matched the search ref:http://developer.yahoo.com/search/boss/boss_api_guide/webv2_response.html.

If I use the totalresults for paging in my page,and i'm show perpage is 10 the page is very much and when i'm execute by $start =10 or $start =20 ...ect, in the next $start =1010 is not run.i'm read the documentation maximum of $start is 1000 .

How i can find the lastpage? or the real totalresult for list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, the maximum start value is 1000, so you could set your UI "total pages" to be 1000 divided by number you're showing on each page.

Per the [Universal BOSS API Arguments](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/boss/boss_api_guide/v2_univer_api_args.html):

> Ordinal position of first result. First position is 0. Default sets start to 0. Note: Start parameter cannot be greater than 1000. All services return a maximum of 1000 results only.

All of the search webservices I've seen are designed in a similar way, because they don't want to expose their entire search database. (Also because search results that deep tend to not be that useful.) Some common traits:

- The "total results" value returned is an approximation
- There is a limit as to how deep you can go for a given query

For example in your case your query said that over a billion results were available, but it's not practical to try and fetch each one of those.